# How can I make Plot or ListPlot scale the plot automatically for a given domain?

Tags: plotting

Often, I'll have a list of pairs I want to plot, that goes over some broad range. For example:

```
a = Table[{x, x^5}, {x, -5, 5, .1}];
ListPlot[a]
```

[image]

However, I'll really only want to plot a subset of those points, knowing the sub-domain (i.e., x values, in this case, -2 to 2) I want to plot, but not the range of that sub-domain (the y values). Similarly, I want ListPlot to automatically scale the vertical axis, within this subset. However, if I do:

```
ListPlot[a, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, Automatic}]
```

I get:

[image]

So it's obviously just using the auto range for the full data set still. This makes some sense, because technically I'm still passing it the whole set. So I know one solution is to first cleanse that data set. But at this point it seems like ListPlot could also figure out the points I actually want plotted. Is there a way to make it do this?

Comment: Perhaps `ListPlot@Select[a, -2 < #[[1]] < 2 &]`

Comment: @Alan thanks, but that's what I mean by pre-cleansing the data. I'm currently doing that with a fairly small function I made, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do that just in ListPlot.

Answer (score 3):

A bit awkward, but it works and (as requested) all processing is within the `ListPlot` call:

```
a = Table[{x, x^5}, {x, -5, 5, .1}];
ListPlot[a,
 PlotRange -> {myrange = {-2, 2}, 
     {Min[q = Select[a, myrange[[1]] < #[[1]] < myrange[[2]] &][[All, 2]]], Max[q]}}]
```

Frankly, though, I don't see why it would ever be preferable to do the processing and selection within the `ListPlot` function call, since eliminating the unneeded data points before the call will always be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = Table[{x, x^5}, {x, -5, 5, .1}];

Plot[Interpolation[a][x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0],
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[a]}]
```

[image]

Or to show all of the points in the range {-2, 2}

```
Plot[Interpolation[a][x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], 
 PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[a]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to use `Interpolation`:

Use it to specify the second part of `PlotRange` setting:

```
ListPlot[a, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, Interpolation[a] /@ {-2, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, a variation of @BobHanlon's approach using `Mesh`:

```
Plot[Interpolation[a]@x, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Full,
 Mesh -> {a[[All, 1]]},  MeshShading -> {None, None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]